# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I am getting an exception exception when attempting to run a Java sample application.

Below is a stack trace from the console:

```
    $./init-og-examples-db.sh
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/Task
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Task
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/Task
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Task
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
### Adding example data
Error: Could not find or load main class com.opengamma.examples.tool.ExampleDatabasePopulator
### Completed
```

I am relatively new to Java, so I am not sure why the class is not been found, since the class does exist:

```
someone@yourbox:~/work/dev/java/OG-Platform/projects/OG-Examples/scripts$ find ../../.. -type f -name 'ExampleDatabasePopulator.*'
../../../projects/OG-Examples/bin/com/opengamma/examples/tool/ExampleDatabasePopulator.class
../../../projects/OG-Examples/build/classes/com/opengamma/examples/tool/ExampleDatabasePopulator.class
../../../projects/OG-Examples/src/main/java/com/opengamma/examples/tool/ExampleDatabasePopulator.java
../../../projects/OG-BloombergExample/bin/com/opengamma/bloombergexample/tool/ExampleDatabasePopulator.class
../../../projects/OG-BloombergExample/build/classes/com/opengamma/bloombergexample/tool/ExampleDatabasePopulator.class
../../../projects/OG-BloombergExample/src/main/java/com/opengamma/bloombergexample/tool/ExampleDatabasePopulator.java
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

**[Update]**

I have done the following:

**1.** Removed and manually installed ant on my machine

**2.** Searched for .jar files containing the word Task (in an attempt to find the file that implements the Task class)

```
grep -lri Task --include=*.jar /usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-netrexx.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jdepend.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-javamail.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-junit.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jsch.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-junit4.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jmf.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-testutil.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jai.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-commons-net.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-antlr.jar
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-swing.jar
```

**3.** Added the relevant folders to my CLASSPATH

> export
>   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/etc:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib

**4.** Made sure that I have both `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` set correctly

```
echo $ANT_HOME
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
```

Still, I get exactly the same errors as before (i.e. stack trace is same as that above).

**[2nd Update]**

This is the contents of the script file I am running:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
elif [ -x /opt/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java ]; then
  JAVA=/opt/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java
else
  # No JAVA_HOME, try to find java in the path
  JAVA=`which java 2>/dev/null`
  if [ ! -x "$JAVA" ]; then
    # No java executable in the path either
    echo "Error: Cannot find a JRE or JDK. Please set JAVA_HOME"
    exit 1
  fi
fi

if [ "`basename $0`" = "init-og-examples-db.sh" ] ; then
  cd `dirname $0`/.. #PLAT-1527
fi

CLASSPATH=config:og-examples.jar
for FILE in `ls -1 lib/*` ; do
  CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$FILE
done

echo "### Creating empty database"

$JAVA  -cp "$CLASSPATH" \
  -Dlogback.configurationFile=jetty-logback.xml \
  com.opengamma.util.test.DbTool \
  -jdbcUrl jdbc:hsqldb:file:install/db/hsqldb/example-db \
  -database og-financial \
  -user "OpenGamma" \
  -password "OpenGamma" \
  -drop true \
  -create true \
  -createtables true \
  -dbscriptbasedir .

$JAVA  -cp "$CLASSPATH" \
  -Dlogback.configurationFile=jetty-logback.xml \
  com.opengamma.util.test.DbTool \
  -jdbcUrl jdbc:hsqldb:file:temp/hsqldb/og-fin-user \
  -database og-financial \
  -user "OpenGamma" \
  -password "OpenGamma" \
  -drop true \
  -create true \
  -createtables true \
  -dbscriptbasedir .

echo "### Adding example data"

$JAVA  -cp "$CLASSPATH" \
  -Xms512M \
  -Xmx1024M \
  -Dlogback.configurationFile=jetty-logback.xml \
  com.opengamma.examples.tool.ExampleDatabasePopulator

echo "### Completed"
```

Comment: You don't have the `.jar` file that contains the class  `org.apache.tools.ant.Task` in your classpath.

Comment: For finding a jar,I suggest the site http://www.findjar.com/index.x

Comment: Can you please also post the shell script used to run the program?

Comment: @UwePlonus: I have added the contents of the shell script that generates the error above, as requested. I will be away from my desk for about 12hrs now, so if you have any questions, I will respond when I get back. Tx for your help.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli if you script file is the complete file then you're resetting the `CLASSPATH`. It looks like you're not retaining your `CLASSPATH` which is set outside the script.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Could you please print the output of the final $CLASSPATH?

Comment: @UwePlonus: You set me on the correct path. I can't imagine why I didn't inspect the shell script. I ammended it not to overwrite my existing CLASSPATH, and now the ant error is gone, there is another error now, but it is unrelated to this issue, and I think I can solve it from this point onwards. Thanks for your help!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that your `CLASSPATH` is not valid for your execution. Your `CLASSPATH` must be

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/etc:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-jai.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-swing.jar
```

If you name only a directory only the `.class` files from the directory will be included.

`.jar` files must be named explicitly in the `CLASSPATH` as they are not included automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your more detailed answer. I changed my CLASSPATH as you kindly pointed out, and then run the demo again. I still got an exception and stack trace (please see updated question for stack trace). I can't help but feel that there is something simple that I am missing - but, its very frustrating as I am stuck on this error.

Comment: It appears I can't award the bounty till after 20hrs from hence.... I'll try again later.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain the idiosyncrasies of CLASSPATH to a Java newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The `ant` jars seem to be missing. You can download them from [here](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) and them to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I think I already have ant: `someone@yourbox:~/work/dev/java/OG-Platform/projects/OG-Examples/scripts$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011` Do I still need to download ant?

Comment: Your application is searching for the `Task` class from the org.apache.tools.ant` package which it needs to execute.

Comment: remember to set the ANT_HOME path variable

Comment: @Junaid: Please see my updated question. I have done as you and others have suggested and the issue remains resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases works by adding a `:.` at the end. For example:

`export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/etc:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.1/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:.`